# OnScreen keyboard not showing in FlutterFlow Test mode

Tags: flutterflow

I'm playing with FlutteFlow and faced an issue.
When I run my app in Test mode and focus on Text field OnScreen keyboard doesn't show.
I'm using Chrome, also was trying with Edge.

The problem is that I have a button which is visible only when keyboard is visible. No keyboard - no button.

How to force OnScreen keyboard to be shown on focus?

Answer (score 0):

From searching around, it appears you are not the only one to have this issue. In test mode, I believe FlutterFlow defaults to using your computer keyboard. However, you can toggle the keyboard to show by clicking a button in the building/testing interface. See [Point 11](https://docs.flutterflow.io/getting-started/ui-builder/canvas-area#id-11.-display-keyboard) from the FlutterFlow canvas area docs:

> 11. Display Keyboard: Enabling this option opens up the keyboard on the device preview screen; this helps in visualizing the user interface with the keyboard displayed. Opening up the keyboard usually pushes the contents of the screen upwards.

[image: FlutterFlow Toolbar]